# Can't add custom attributes to MappedColumn, AttributeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to add an attribute, "_editable", to my `MappedColumn` class in SQLAlchemy. To do this I am creating a custom constructor that calls the `mapped_column` constructor and adding the attribute. I would like to add this attribute without extending the `MappedColumn` class because this would require me to copy everything in the original `mapped_column` constructor.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column as mc
from sqlalchemy.orm.properties import MappedColumn

def mapped_column(*args, editable=True, **kwargs) -> MappedColumn[Any]:
    new_mc = mc(*args, **kwargs)
    new_mc._editable = editable
    return new_mc
```

When I use this in my models I get the following error:

```
  File ".../src/util.py", line 53, in mapped_column
    new_mc._editable = editable
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MappedColumn' object has no attribute '_editable'
```